# Is there a way to give custom options to a babel plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, babeljs

I might be wrong but i couldn't find any solution to give some custom options to my custom babel plugin. Do you have any clue how i could achieve this ?

Here is my building process, i'm using gulp with browserify and babelify :

```
gulp.task("scripts", function() {
    return browserify({
        entries: "myFile.js"
    })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
        plugins: ["./lib/myPlugin:after"]
    }))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("all.js"))
    .pipe("build/");
});
```

I would like to give some custom data to my plugin, doing something like this :

```
gulp.task("scripts", function() {
    return browserify({
        entries: "myFile.js"
    })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
        myCustomOptions: {
            rootPath: "some path",
            customInfo: "..."
        }
        plugins: ["./lib/myPlugin:after"]
    }))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("all.js"))
    .pipe("build/");
});
```

Then in my plugin, i would like to retrieve the customOptions object i just declared. Would there be a way to achieve something like that ?

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has changed recently in **Babel 6**. From [the docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/):

> Plugins can specify options. You can do so in your config by wrapping it in an array and providing a options object. For example:
>
> ```
> {
>   "plugins": [
>     ["transform-async-to-module-method", {
>       "module": "bluebird",
>       "method": "coroutine"
>     }]
>   ]
> }
> ```

[Plugin Options](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#toc-plugin-options) documentation in the Babel plugin handbook.

Comment: I cannot find a way to access plugin options at the plugin function scope. It seems it is possible to access `state.opts` only from the visitor scope.

Comment: I don't have a solution for that but i just wanted to point the documentation about plugin options : https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#toc-plugin-options

Answer (score 3):

I found a way out but i'm pretty sure it's not a proper way to go :

Reading babel code, it seems there is a hidden option called "extra". I used that option to push my custom options :

```
gulp.task("scripts", function() {
    return browserify({
        entries: "myFile.js"
    })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
        extra: {
            myPlugin: {
                // here i put my custom data
            }
        },
        plugins: ["./lib/myPlugin:after"]
    }))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("all.js"))
    .pipe("build/");
});
```

Then in my plugin i can retrieve my custom options like this :

```
var myPlugin = function(babel) {
    var t = babel.types;
    var pluginConf;

    return new babel.Transformer("babel-platform", {
        CallExpression(node, parent, scope, config) {
            pluginConf = pluginConf || config.opts.extra["myPlugin"] || {};
            // Doing some stuff here on the CallExpression
        }
    });
}
```

I know this is definitely not a proper way. Would you have any alternatives ?