# How to pass params to plugins in presets in babel 6?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a [react preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/), and I want to pass pragma params to transform-react-jsx.

For now I’m installing [transform-react-jsx](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/) separatly and set my `.babelrc` like so:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx", {
      "pragma": "dom.hJSX"
    }]
  ]
}
```

But I wonder if there is another way to pass settings to plugins in presets.

Comment: what's a `react preset` ? So... are there options? What kinds of search phrases did you  try sir?

Comment: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/

Comment: That seems pretty neat, though it's still not clicking with me yet. This is like KnockOut or Jquery I guess?

Comment: I’ve edited my question to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got to babel github and as I found out now [there is no way](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2990) to pass settings to plugins in presets.

On the bright side there is [another discussion](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2756) that could turn into something sometime sooner or later.

**UPD:** babel moved all issues to phabricator and these discussions seem to be lost forever. However [this feature](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#a-traversal-per-preset-experimental) seems to be a step forward towards solving the issue.

Comment: These links are dead, and this is the only reference I'm finding to this problem ... did you ever find a way around it?

Comment: @Semicolon unfortunately no, I still use separate plugins as a hack.

And since they moved all the issues from github to phabricator, these issues are seemingly lost

Comment: I’ve read through latest changelog and it seems that they are moving towards custom plugin options in presets with traversal per preset feature: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#a-traversal-per-preset-experimental

Comment: This is now possible via `pragma` option to `transform-react-jsx`. Ref: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/

Comment: I found the answer I needed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776907/is-there-a-way-to-give-custom-options-to-a-babel-plugin